# How to add hamburger-icon in navigation react-native v2

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

I have this code in App.js (I'm using CRNA create-react-native-app).

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Navigator, Image} from 'react-native';
import {Container, Content, Header, Body, Icon} from 'native-base';

import UserLocation from './pages/UserLocation';
import ShopNow from './pages/ShopNow';
import ItemFavorite from './pages/ItemFavorite';

import {createStackNavigator,createDrawerNavigator, DrawerItems} from 'react-navigation';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
  }

  static navigationOptions = { 
    title:'Welcome',
    headerLeft: 
      <View style={{paddingLeft:16}}>
        <Icon
          name="md-menu"
          size={30}
          color='black'
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')} />
      </View>
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AppStackNavigator/>
      //<MyAppDrawer/>

    );
  }
}

const CustomDrawer = (props) => (
  <Container>
    <Header style={{
      height:200
    }}>

      <Body>
        <Image
          style={styles.drawerImage}
          source={require('./images/logo.png')}
        />
      </Body>
    </Header>
    <Content>
      <DrawerItems {...props} />
    </Content>
  </Container>

)

const MyAppDrawer = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: UserLocation
  },
  Shop: {
    screen: ShopNow
  },
  Favorite: {
    screen: ItemFavorite
  }
},{
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
  contentComponent: CustomDrawer,
  drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
  drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
  drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
});

const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Drawer: {screen: MyAppDrawer},
  App: { 
    screen: UserLocation,
    // navigationOptions:{
    //   title:'Welcome',
    //   headerLeft: 
    //   <View style={{paddingLeft:16}}>
    //     <Icon
    //       name="md-menu"
    //       size={30}
    //       color='black'
    //       onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')} />
    //   </View>
    // }

  },
  ShopNow: { screen: ShopNow },
  ItemFavorite: { screen: ItemFavorite}
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  drawerImage: {
    height: 150,
    width: 150,
    borderRadius: 75
  }
});
```

I don't know why anywhere I put the `static navigationOptions`, it doesn't change the header of the first page.

I also tried using the `static navigationOptions.headerLeft` in the specific page to add hamburger-icon, it doesn't work.

But in the page 'ItemFavorite' at the bottom of the file I set this:

```
ItemFavorite.navigationOptions = {
    drawerIcon: (
        <Image source={require('../images/tablet.png')} style={{ height: 24, width: 24 }} />
    ),
    title: 'Favorite Item',
    headerLeft: <Text onPress={() => 
        navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}>Menu</Text>
}
```

it works! But not working in the first page of stack.

Do I miss something here?

Answer (score 0):

You need put Your View in same line as headerLeft

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Navigator, Image} from 'react-native';
import {Container, Content, Header, Body, Icon} from 'native-base';

import UserLocation from './pages/UserLocation';
import ShopNow from './pages/ShopNow';
import ItemFavorite from './pages/ItemFavorite';

import {createStackNavigator,createDrawerNavigator, DrawerItems} from 'react-navigation';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
  }

  static navigationOptions = { 
    title:'Welcome',
    headerLeft: <View style={{paddingLeft:16}}>
        <Icon
          name="md-menu"
          size={30}
          color='black'
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')} />
      </View>
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AppStackNavigator/>
      //<MyAppDrawer/>

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I've already done that.. but the thing is it doesn't show anything in the 1st stack. My createStackNavigator and createDrawerNavigator is in App.js, with initial route to pages/FirstPage.js. The navigationOptions works in pages/SecondPage.js and also pages/ThirdPage.js.. so if I want to put the header Navigation in the first page, should i put it in App.js or pages/FirstPage.js?

Comment: Can you show me you stackNavigation code  .... so that i can know exactly why is this happening.